# Is there a way to avoid adding a dot after title or author in the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, swedish

I want to make an APA reference in my text. The reference is a legal text and it must be referenced in this way: "*Skollagen* (SFS-2010:800). Utbildningsdepartementet."

I've used `@book` like this:

```
@book{law_2010:800, 
title = {\textit{Skollagen }},
URL = {https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/dokument-lagar/dokument/svensk-forfattningssamling/skollag-2010800_sfs-2010-800},
URLDATE = {2023-07-05}, 
PUBLISHER  = {{Utbildningsdepartementet}},
YEAR = {SFS-2010:800}
}
```

With this result: "*Skollagen*. (SFS-2010:800). Utbildningsdepartementet."

The problem is that I don't want the dot after *Skollagen*

My main.tex looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor,xurl,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{projekt.bib} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{swedish}{swedish-apa}


\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}      
    \printbibliography[title=Referenser]    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: You don't need the `\textit` wrapper in the `title` field. And, because you load the `babel` package with the language option `swedish`, you don't need to set the option `title=Referenser` when executing `\printbibliography`. Incidentally, I've taken the liberty of making your test file more minimal; feel free to revert.